# What can be concluded from an ANOVA interaction effect?

Tags: anova, linear-model

Imagine that I run an ANOVA with two variables, x and y, that both have two levels (let's say a/b and c/d). Further, let's say that I get no main effects but an interaction effect.

My question now is: What is it that I can conclude from this interaction effect? My own take on this is that the only thing that I can conclude is that in the underlying linear model, one needs the level of x for a certain cell to be able to say how much y should add or subtract to/from the final value of the cell (and vice versa when computing the contribution of x where one needs the level of y).

That is, I claim that one from an interaction effect cannot draw any conclusions regarding significant differences between any combination of data points (for example, that a is different from d, or that the mean of ac is different from the mean of cd) in the actual data.

Is this correct?